# Unity sprites are stretched on iPhone X

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, sprite, game-development, unity-ui

I have sprites for game ui/canvases and they are stretched on iPhone X view. When I scale for iPhone X, they become stretched on other iPhones.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check "Preserve Aspect" box of your image at inspector.

Answer (score 1):

Answer was just to place anchors in right place, they need to not be on all of corners of sprite, just add them to the center of the sprite and all in the same position, it fixes the problem!